# fast parallel picking/checking of some ID (think non-game application of loot lag)

Tags: multithreading, performance, algorithm, thread-safety, multiprocessing

So I am verifying new operational management systems, and one of these OS's sends pick lists to a scale-able number of handheld devices. It sends these using messages, and their pick lists may contain overlapping jobs. So in my virtual world, I need to make sure that two simulated humans don't pick the same job - whenever someone picks a job, all the job lists get refreshed, so that the picked job doesn't appear on anyone else's handheld anymore, but for me the message is still in the queue being handled, so I have to make sure to discard that option.

Basically I have this giant list with a mutex, and the more "people" hitting it faster, the slower I can handle messages, to the point where I'm no longer at real-time, which is bad, because I can't actually validate the system because I can't keep up with the messages. (two guys on the same isle will recognize that one is going to pick one object and the next guy should pick the 2nd item, but I need to check every single job i'm about to pick and see if it has been claimed by someone else already)

I've considered localized binning of the lists, but it actually doesn't solve the problem in the stupid case that breaks it anyway, tons of people working on the same row. Now granted this would probably be confusing for the real people as well, as in real life they need to do the same resolution, but I'm curious what the currently accepted "best" solution to this problem is.

PS - I already am implementing this in c++ and it's fast, fast enough that in any practical test I don't "need" this question answered, it's more because I'm curious that I'm asking.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I may not be understanding the problem correctly, but if I am, perhaps a lock-free hash table would be the way to go?  (Assuming each of your jobs has a unique ID, the hash table would give you O(1) lookup and removal times, and that might be sufficient; if not you can find a lock-free hash table so you can avoid the mutex and allow concurrent access to the table from multiple threads; note that lock-free data structures can be tricky to get 100% right though)

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem in the design "giant list with (one) mutex". You simply can't provide the whole list in synchronized fashion, if the list size and/or access rate is unlimited. Basic math works against you. So what i would do is a mutexed flag on each job. You can't prevent a job from being displayed on someone's screen, but you can assure that he gets a graceful "no more available" error and THEN the updated list. If you ever wanted to reserve a seat on highly popular gig, you may have witnessed the solution.